# Making rsync quicker when going from server -> PC

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to work out how I can speed up my backups going from my UNIX server, to my Windows 10 64bit PC. I'm currently using the following command:

```
rsync -vcr --chmod=ugo=rwX --delete --whole-file -e "ssh -l chambres -i /cygdrive/F/ServerBackups/com_server_key" --exclude '*.compiled' --exclude 'GTTemp*' --exclude 'backup' --exclude 'Detailed' --exclude 'Gites/' --exclude 'Chambres_D_Hotes/' --exclude 'public_html/m/' "site.com:/home/user/public_html" "/cygdrive/F/ServerBackups/Account" > /cygdrive/F/ServerBackups/Account.log
```

It's run using *Cygwin*, but on a *Windows 10* machine. The site is about 100gb, but I was hoping that it would be quicker than this when actually grabbing the changed files.

The `--exclude` stuff is meant to speed it up (as those are just static pages, that get built every night, so I don't really care about those)

Currently it's taking 7-8 hours to run, and maxing out my CPU's for a lot of the time (I'm on a 8 core Intel i7, 3.24ghz... so not exactly a small machine :))

Are there any tricks I can use, to try and speed it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the `-c` option. It needs to read all files on both the server and the client to calculate/compare checksums.

In most cases, time/size based comparison (as used by `rsync -av`) should be sufficient.

Citing `man rsync`:

> -c, --checksum
>
> This changes the way rsync checks if the files have been changed and are in need of a transfer.   Without  this  option,  rsync
>                 uses  a  "quick  check" that (by default) checks if each file's size and time of last modification match between the sender and
>                 receiver.  This option changes this to compare a 128-bit checksum for each file that  has  a  matching  size.   Generating  the
>                 checksums  means  that  both sides will expend a lot of disk I/O reading all the data in the files in the transfer (and this is
>                 prior to any reading that will be done to transfer changed files), so this can slow things down significantly.
>
> The sending side generates its checksums while it is doing the file-system scan that builds the list of  the  available  files.
>                 The  receiver  generates its checksums when it is scanning for changed files, and will checksum any file that has the same size
>                 as the corresponding sender's file:  files with either a changed size or a changed checksum are selected for transfer.
>
> Note that rsync always verifies that each transferred file was correctly reconstructed on the  receiving  side  by  checking  a
>                 whole-file  checksum that is generated as the file is transferred, but that automatic after-the-transfer verification has noth-
>                 ing to do with this option's before-the-transfer "Does this file need to be updated?" check.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So are you saying change `-vcr` to just `-av` , or just remove the "c" from `-vcr` ? Thanks : )

Comment: Change it to `rsync -av`. `-a` includes `-rlptgoD`. See `man rsync`.

Comment: Thanks - giving that a go now. I'll mark your answer as correct, even though it'll take a while to run through :)

Comment: Is it normal for it to re-download everything after changing the flags? Seems to be going over everything now. EDIT: Never mind, I just cancelled it after one test site, then re-run, and it works perfectly - super fast now! Thanks :)

Comment: Just an update on this. It has made a HUGE difference with my backups! It's now gone from 9+ hours to backup (and quite high CPU usage), to about 30 minutes for 6 different sites. Thanks!